# Present continuous and adverb frequently

Tags: adverbs, present-continuous

Why in the following example we can't (or maybe shouldn't) use the same adverb **frequently** instead of **always** in the second sentence that has the same meaning as the first?

I **frequently** lose my glasses.
I'm **always** losing my glasses.

Comment: "loss" is a noun, do u mean "frequently lose"? BTW, what do you want to imply?

Comment: Why we can't say I'm losing my glasses frequently? There are many more similar examples in Oxford English Result that the author replace frequently with always when he wants to change the sentence to equivalent present continuous.

Comment: I am not in the place to answer this question, but that structure "always+present progressive" is used to talk about our habits or to emphasize the characteristics

Comment: @Cardinal - "U?" Really?

Comment: @P.E.Dant OK, :-), I should've used "you"- the correct word.

Comment: @Cardinal - Please help us hold back the tide of one-letter words and monosyllabic grunts!

Comment: @P.E.Dant... monosyllabic words like P and E, for example?

Comment: initials r exempted. u know that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary (meaning 1.3)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/always), we use a continuous tense with **always** when we want to talk about something that happens **repeatedly and annoyingly**.

Compare that with using **always** in the present simple (meaning 1.1) - at all times; on all occasions

> I am always ready *- At all times*
>  
>   I am always nervous when I have to speak before a large group of people *- on all occasions*

[frequently](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frequently) is defined as regularly; habitually; often: we use it to talk about a number of separate instances that happen at regular intervals, and is only ever used with the a simple tense- as if we are talking about each instance separately.

Answer (score -3):

If something frequently happens, simple tense must be used.

Therefore, 'frequently' is/can be used in the first sentence  and not in the second one. Moreover, 'Always' should also not be used in the second sentence. In a nutshell, first sentence is correct, but not the second one.

Comment: (-1) Although I am a novice and leaner, I am sure that you are wrong.

Comment: One of the uses of present continuous is describing something which happens frequently and is annoying.

Comment: If credited as correct, this answer will frequently cause mistakes in grammar. This has frequently been the case.